# Simple schema … index of [object]

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema

```
field1: {
  type : [Xschema]
}
xschema: {
  totalSalary: {
    type: Number,
  },
  basicSalary: {
    type: Number,
    autoform: {
      firstOption: false,
      options: function () {
        var length = _.size(AutoForm.getFieldValue('salaryDetails'));
        var str = 'salaryDetails.' + (length - 1) + '.totalSalary';
        var salary = AutoForm.getFieldValue(str);
        return {label:salary*0.6};
      }
    }
  },
}
```

in the autoform when i click on the + to add more object of the xschema all the previous fields of the 'basic salary' get the same value for example : all basic salaries are filled with the last amount calculated

to clarify it more

total salary : 1000 -> basic salary (auto calculation) : 600

click to add +

total salary : 100 -> basic salary (auto calculation) : 60 and at the same the previous basic salary turns to be 60 as well

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. In what context are you trying to use the index? In the schema definition itself?

Comment: yeah inside the autoform->options ... i am making some calculations for each entry i add .. thats why i need the index ... did you get my point or you want me to post the code ?

Comment: i did edit the whole thing ... hope now it is more clearer